# Android - Layer-List Rounded Rectangle Issue

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, rounding, rounded-corners

I've created a layer-list drawable with overlapping round rectangles to create a shadow but started to noticed a weird issue with the bottom layer peeking thru when the corner radius is used.  So as a test, I just layered two rounded rectangles and the behavior exists.  Is this a possible issue?

[image: Example]

If you look at A, you'll notice the corners displaying the bottom layer's color.  I switched the top layer's color to white and as you can see there is something going on here as you can see the corners showing up when they should not.  Below is the drawable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: what exacrly do you have problem with?

Comment: The curved red corners that should not be there.

Comment: no, everything is ok, its a sidw effect of antyaliasing, take any pixel based graphical tool, create two circles of different color and place one of them on top of another